# How will get system file separator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, separator

How will get system file separator in javascript? Now I use forward slash. But it makes issues.

```
var coverletterPath = serverPath.substring(0, serverPathIndex) + "/docs/" + docPath + "/";
```

Comment: Where does the JS run? If it is in the browser, the file system separator is irrelevant (and the URL separator is always a forward-slash). And *please accept answers to your previous questions*.

Answer (score 0):

use **path** module for handling files in OS file system.